# how to show this first ode is Homogeneous ODE of Class D?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Maple has type of ode called `Homogeneous ODEs of Class D` defined as shown [here](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/helpjp/maple/view.aspx?path=odeadvisor%2FhomogeneousD)

Here is screen shot also

[image]

But it says the following ode below is of the above type. I am having hard time seeing how this matches the above form. i.e. what is $g(x)$ and $f$ in the following ode? I tried few manipulations. The problem is there is no $f$ function in this ode at all. Here is the ode:

$$
y^{\prime}=-\frac{y\left(  y^{2}+3x^{2}+2x\right)  }{x^{2}+y^{2}}
$$

Which expands to

\begin{align*}
y^{\prime}  & =-\frac{y^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}-\frac{3yx^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}
-\frac{2xy}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\\
& =-\frac{y}{\left(  \frac{x}{y}\right)  ^{2}+1}-\frac{3y}{1+\left(  \frac
{y}{x}\right)  ^{2}}-\frac{2\frac{y}{x}}{1+\left(  \frac{y}{x}\right)  ^{2}
}\\
& =-y\frac{3x^{2}+y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}-\frac{2\frac{y}{x}}{1+\left(  \frac
{y}{x}\right)  ^{2}}\\
& =-y\frac{3+\left(  \frac{y}{x}\right)  ^{2}}{1+\left(  \frac{y}{x}\right)
^{2}}-\frac{2\frac{y}{x}}{1+\left(  \frac{y}{x}\right)  ^{2}}\\
& =-\frac{3y+y\left(  \frac{y}{x}\right)  ^{2}}{1+\left(  \frac{y}{x}\right)
^{2}}-\frac{2\frac{y}{x}}{1+\left(  \frac{y}{x}\right)  ^{2}}
\end{align*}

I give up. Maple says this ode is `Homogeneous ODEs of Class D`

```
ode := diff(y(x), x) = -y(x)*(y(x)^2 + 3*x^2 + 2*x)/(x^2 + y(x)^2);
DEtools:-odeadvisor(ode)
```

[image]

The question is, what would be $g(x)$ and $f(y/x)$ for the above ode in order to make it match the form given by Maple web page? i.e. how to write it so it match the form on the web page?

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha surprisingly finds a closed-form solution for the ODE. So if you are interested in the solution: [see here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=DSolve%5By%27%5Bx%5D+%3D%3D+-%28%28y%5Bx%5D+%282+x+%2B+3+x%5E2+%2B+y%5Bx%5D%5E2%29%29%2F%28x%5E2+%2B+y%5Bx%5D%5E2%29%29%2C+y%5Bx%5D%2C+x%5D)

Answer (score 1):

$$y^{\prime}=-\frac{y\left(  y^{2}+3x^{2}+2x\right)  }{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$
I was not able to rewrite the DE as in the expected form of Maple but here is my approach:
$$(x^2+y^2)y'+y(2x+2yy')=-{y\left(  y^{2}+3x^{2}\right) +2y^2y' }$$
$$((x^2+y^2)y)'+3y(x^2+y^3)=2y^3+2y^2y' $$
$$(((x^2+y^2)y)e^{3x})'=2e^{3x}(y^3+y^2y') $$
$$(((x^2+y^2)y)e^{3x})'=\dfrac 23(e^{3x}y^3)' $$
$$((x^2+y^2)y)e^{3x}=\dfrac 23e^{3x}y^3+c$$
$$\left((3x^2+y^2)y\right)e^{3x}=C $$